# Select Locked record in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use this Tsql to select locked object in my database:

```
select  
    object_name(P.object_id) as TableName, 
    resource_type, resource_description
from
    sys.dm_tran_locks L join sys.partitions P
                   on L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
```

but this only show me the table that are lock now.how can i show the locked record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will help you find all the current requests on SQL Server and their statuses. I believe you cannot go to the record level. I maybe wrong on that.

```
SELECT r.session_id, r.status, r.start_time, r.command, s.text, 
r.wait_time, r.cpu_time, r.total_elapsed_time, r.reads, r.writes, r.logical_reads, r.transaction_isolation_level 
,r.* 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
```

The following will tell you what is blocking your request.

```
select distinct object_name(a.rsc_objid), a.req_spid, b.loginame 
from master.dbo.syslockinfo a (nolock) join 
master.dbo.sysprocesses b (nolock) on a.req_spid=b.spid 
where object_name(a.rsc_objid) is not null
```

Comment: no ii is not the answer.first sql only show me the sql commands that we use in current batch.and the other sql command only show the table that are lock now.but i want to show the locked record of each table that are locked now

Comment: I dont think there is a way to find out the exact record which has been locked. You may want to write a cursor statement to see the output of every row operation. This way can help you determine which record has been locked upon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (undocumented) method!
I know that is too late, but for a people that still searching the answer:

```
SELECT <main_key>
FROM <table>
WHERE %%lockres%% IN ( select dm_tran_locks.resource_description from sys.dm_tran_locks )
```